# What is throwing the error the static or the const?

Tags: c++, class, object, static, constants

The following code is throwing an error message and I can't figure out what the issue is - is it the word `static`, or `const`? What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class SampleClass
{
private:

    int value;
    static int counter;

public:

    SampleClass(int i)
    {
        value = i; 
        counter++;
    }

    static int countSomeClass() const
    {
        return counter;
    }

    void showValue()
    {
        cout << value << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    SampleClass test(50);
    test.showValue();
    test.countSomeClass();
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

> main.cpp:16:35: error: static member function static int SampleClass::countSomeClass() cannot have cv-qualifier
>      static int countSomeClass() const

Comment: A `static` function cannot be `const`. It is the combination that is the problem.

Comment: access specifier - read about those

Comment: @hagubear: How is that relevant? The function is public, so access isn't the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A `static` method cannot be marked as `const`: since it doesn't work on an instance, it makes no sense to specify that it cannot modify it.

(you could argue that for `static` methods it could have referred to `static` methods that cannot modify the `static` data associated with the class; however, this would have no use anyway, since you cannot have a `const` class or form a `const` pointer or reference to a class, as in C++ classes aren't objects)

Comment: after removing `const` the following message appears `/tmp/ccYI99mO.o: In function `SampleClass::SampleClass(int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN11SampleClassC2Ei[_ZN11SampleClassC5Ei]+0x16): undefined reference to `SampleClass::counter'`

Comment: @YelizavetaYR; your `counter` is declared but not defined (outside the class). It requires something like `int SampleClass::counter = 0;` in one of the translation units (cpp file).

Answer (score 13):

As the error message says, a static member function can't have a *cv-qualifier* - that is, a `const` or `volatile` qualifier. Such qualifiers are applied to `this` within a non-static member; they make no sense on a static member which has no `this`.

You want the function to be static, since it doesn't depend on any instance; so remove the `const`.

Answer (score 12):

A `static` function cannot be `const` (cv-qualified) and vice-versa. It is the *combination* of the two that is the problem.

From the C++ specification § 9.4.1/2 (emphasis mine)

> [ Note: A `static` member function does not have a `this` pointer (9.3.2). —end note ] A `static` member function shall not be `virtual`. There shall not be a `static` and a non-static member function with the same name and the same parameter types (13.1). **A `static` member function shall not be declared `const`, `volatile`, or `const volatile`.**

A `static` function has no `this` access since it is not associated with a specific instance of an object. There is no need for a `const` to be applied, it wouldn't make sense - there is no instance of an object to apply the `const` to. In a similar way, a free function cannot be `const` (or *cv-qualified*).

If you wish the function to be associated with an object, remove the `static`, if you want it to be `static` remove the `const` - **from your sample, remove the `const`**.

One more note; your `counter` is declared but not defined (outside the class). It requires something like `int SampleClass::counter = 0;` in one of the translation units (cpp file).

Answer (score 5):

It's related to both.

- A `static` member function **does not work on an instance** of the class it's a member of.
- The `const` keyword at the end of a member function signature indicates that this member function does not modify **the instance it's called on**.

So it makes no sense (and is thus invalid) to have both in the same member function declaration.